# Weird Error. 8007007E : Retrieving the COM class factory for component{} - 8007007E

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-6, com+, dcom

I have deployed a Web Application(developed in VS 2008) on Windows 2003 Server 32bit OS.
My application uses Microsoft Office Word(i am using it to Generate PDF).
Application is running perfectly fine, .Doc & .Pdf are being generated. 
But once i restart the server i get the above mentioned error **(8007007E)** only 1st time, after i refresh the page, the application starts to work properly again.
i looked up various causes of the error, but none of them match mine.
usually this when this error occurs it causes complete breakdown of COM usage. 
code sample is below.

```
string htmlContent = div_Data.InnerHtml;
string filename = strLoanNo + strTime + ".doc";
if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Doc/")))
{
 Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Doc/"));
}
System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
div_Data.RenderControl(hw);
FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Doc/") + filename,FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
sw.Write(tw.ToString());
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
fs.Close();

object fileName = Server.MapPath("~/Doc/") + filename;
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object readOnly = false;
object isVisible = true;
object SaveChanges = true;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oWordDoc = appWord.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
oWordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(Server.MapPath("~/Doc/") + strLoanNo + "_" + strTime + ".pdf", WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, false, WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForPrint, WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument, 1, 1, WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentWithMarkup, true, false, WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, false, true, true, ref missing);
((_Document)oWordDoc).Close(ref SaveChanges, ref missing, ref missing);
 appWord.Quit(ref SaveChanges, ref missing, ref missing);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(appWord);

Response.Clear();
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + strLoanNo + "_" + strTime + ".pdf");
        Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/Doc/") + strLoanNo + "_" + strTime + ".pdf");
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();

if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Doc/") + strLoanNo + strTime + ".doc"))
{
  File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/Doc/") + strLoanNo + strTime + ".doc");
}
if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Doc/") + strLoanNo + strTime + ".pdf"))
{
  File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/Doc/") + strLoanNo + strTime + ".pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if code matters at this point, because the issue is probably with a DLL somewhere, however only the system admin will be able to tell you which one is struggling. If you can, use Process monitor to isolate what component is failing https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx.

Thanks,
Apex

Comment: if it was a DLL issue wouldn't it give errors again and again ?

Comment: I could be wrong but i'm pretty sure COM DLLS are loaded on demand whenever the corresponding COM object is created (obviously this doesn't mean that you have an issue with a COM DLL, it could be any DLL) . So sounds like there is a delay between initial load and DLL load, just a theory, i still think you should isolate. Hope it helps.

Comment: i think the DLL's Load on Demand theory seems pretty accurate, since no matter how much i wait after restart the the first instance always throws an error. to convert Doc to Pdf i did install a few additions Microsoft plugins...could be that they are not starting along with COM services